# How to display Persona Card on hover in list using Sharepoint Online view formatting?

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, sharepoint-list, json-formatting

When in an unformatted sharepoint list you can hover over a person's name to get more information about them, I believe this is called their persona card. How can I keep this functionality having formatted my list with JSON?

For the example below I want each of the people's names from the field PastMembers to have that hover action when displayed.

```
{
  "elmType": "div",
  "forEach": "person in [$PastMembers]",
  "children": [
    {
      "elmType": "div",
      "txtContent": "[$person.title]"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using column formatting or view formatting? If you are already using any json code then please add it to your question. Also, I think it is not possible to add persona card on hover using JSON formatting.

Comment: @GaneshSanap I have updated the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `defaultHoverField` property in JSON as described here:

[Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#default-cards-on-hover-via-formatting)

Comment: Yes thank you! It wasn't around when I first asked the question but is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JSON formatting on you list field, Commonly the code will make the person name be displayed as simple text string instead of a special link in people picker field. I am not sure if there are possible options to keep it as a link which will show the profile card.

Comment: Yeah this is what I mean - the persons name is just a string but I want it to have that special link