# How to retain hover functionality on Person column value when using column formatting and txtContent?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, column-formatting

A `Person` column, with no column formatting, has the desired functionality.

I.e. when you hover over a person's name, you can see their `Person` card etc.

So the starting state of the column formatting is:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json"
}
```

Then I add additional column formatting, with an `if` condition.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$Current_x0020_Assignment] =='', 'Not assigned', [$Current_x0020_Assignment.title])"
}
```

The logic above is saying:

> When the value of the `Current Assignment` column is blank, add the text `Not assigned`,
> otherwise, show the the Person's name.

What happens is that the *text* displays correctly, but I lose the 'hover' functionality that displays the `Person` card etc.

If I try referencing `@currentField`:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$Current_x0020_Assignment] =='', 'Not assigned', @currentField)"
}
```

or `[$Current_x0020_Assignment]`:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$Current_x0020_Assignment] =='', 'Not assigned', [$Current_x0020_Assignment])"
}
```

The `Person` column just displays `[Object Object]`.

Is there a way to apply the desired conditional logic whilst retaining the `hover` functionality when hovering over the Person's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/279675), just defining the `defaultHoverField` property seems to work, ie:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "=if([$Current_x0020_Assignment] =='', 'Not assigned', [$Current_x0020_Assignment.title])",
  "defaultHoverField": "[$Current_x0020_Assignment]" 
}
```

Interestingly, the `hover` functionality is automatically *not* applied to the `Not assigned` text values, which is great (i.e., I don't need to apply extra conditional structures to handle that scenario).