# Using Data from another Column to Populate Name (of employees without email)

Tags: json

I have created a list of all employees with the Primary column set to "Person / Group". Of course, all employees that have an active email address are registered in the Active Directory, but for those that are not in the AD, I would very much like to use a hidden field (called Alternate Name) to replace the empty field that appears in the main "Person" column.

I have tried everything and this is far as I can get, (it shows the Alternate name for those not in the AD but all of the registered users' names now disappear and are replaced with [object Object]

However, if I replace the second [$Name] with something like [$ID] then everything works. What I guess I need to know is, what is the identifier for the Persons name who IS in the AD? (the highlighted name with a small icon that you can hover over for more information)? [image]

```
{
  "$schema": "http://columnformatting.sharepointpnp.com/columnFormattingSchema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
 "txtContent": "=if([$Name] == '' , '[$AltName]', '[$Name]')"
}
```

I would appreciate any advice that you might be able to provide.

Comment: What do you get when you use this `$Name` in the field content for Non-AD users, Does it show any value?.

Comment: No, the cell remains blank. Thank you.

Comment: I think, you are facing similar issue as this article https://www.sharepointeurope.com/sharepoint-json-formatting-check-if-date-time-column-is-blank-empty/ and it has solution also given. Try wrapping it around `toString` and check please.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! With this code, I can get very close to my desired result. It replaces blank Name fields with the name from a secondary column, but I do not know how to identify the descriptor for the directory listing, (the persons name with their icon next to it that you can hover over for more). See the image I added to the OP.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for, to persist hover functionality of a person in column formatting? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/278151/how-to-display-persona-card-on-hover-in-list-using-sharepoint-online-view-format/279675#279675

Comment: Thanks again Pradip. This seems a little beyond my abilities. I'm not using dates anywhere so I don't think this applies. Thanks again for all your help here.